# Is there flutter widget to volume control of child widget?

Tags: flutter, audio, widget, controls

I need that different widgets of project can have different sound volume.
Is it possible in Flutter?
Is there some widget for this task in Flutter? Can I wrap target widget with some other widget to control its sound separately?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.